# Why need the (void *) in the pointer conversion?

Tags: c, pointers

In the following code, why need the `(VOID *)` in the middle of pointer conversion?

Some Context definition:

```
#define VOID      void
typedef unsigned char       UINT8;


ErrorDest = (EFI_ACPI_6_0_GENERIC_HARDWARE_ERROR_SOURCE_STRUCTURE *)
            (VOID *)
            ((UINT8 *)Hest + Hest->Header.Length);
```

Comment: Is `VOID` some strange macro/typedef for `void`, or what? Also, what error you get without `(VOID*)` cast?

Comment: Some context would be helpful, as we cannot guess what any of the (resulting) types really are.

Comment: It smells like a trick to silence conversion warnings... BTW more details must be provided to help you, as a 13K user should really know.....

Comment: @Eiko Sorry for missing context. Just added.

Comment: *Do not* use macros and typedefs like this. If you want `void`, use `void`. If you want '*an unsigned 8-bit number*' then `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Attie Unfortunately, I can do nothing about it. This is often seen in the EDK2 open source codebase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only reason I can see is to prevent the compiler from giving warnings about pointer alignment.

`UINT8` has no alignment requirements.

A `struct` can have other alignment requirements depending on its members. Ususally the alignment requirement of a struct is the same as the largest alignment requirement of its members. If `EFI_ACPI_6_0_GENERIC_HARDWARE_ERROR_SOURCE_STRUCTURE` is an opaque type (that is, it is declared, but its members are unknown), or if it contains members with alignment requirements then the compiler may issue a warning about the alignment.

A `void*` may point to any adress but is excempt from alignment warnings when it is cast to another pointer type, even if that type may have alignment requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be alignment, as pointed out in another answer. But it might as well just be a bug - a failed attempt to dodge incompatible pointer type errors.

Upon writing code such as `this_t* a = (that_t*)b;` you get a compiler error about incompatible types. It is then a somewhat common mistake to attempt to fix this error by writing

```
this_t* a = (void*)(that_t*)b; // bad, dont do this
```

Indeed this silences the compiler error. And instead of a compiler error, we now have a run-time undefined behavior bug, because of strict aliasing violation.

If `EFI_ACPI_6_0_GENERIC_HARDWARE_ERROR_SOURCE_STRUCTURE` doesn't contain a member which is an `uint8_t []`, then the code in the question invokes undefined behavior due to strict aliasing violation.